# Pass data to other ActionMethod in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have several action methods in controller

Here is first , here I receive Interview_id and write it in TempData.

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult WelcomeScreen(Interview interview)
    {
        db.Interview.Add(interview);
        db.SaveChanges();
        Int32 id = interview.Interview_Id;
        TempData["id"] = id;
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Questions");
    }
```

I set  breakpoints here `TempData["id"] = id;` and see that `id`  has value.

Here is next method, here I need to write data from TempData to table.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string question1, string question2, string question3, string question4, string question5, string question6, string question7, string question8, string question9, string question10,Int32 id)
    {
        QuestionBlock question = new QuestionBlock
        {
            Question1 = question1,
            Question2 = question2,
            Question3 = question3,
            Question4 = question4,
            Question5 = question5,
            Question6 = question6,
            Question7 = question7,
            Question8 = question8,
            Question9 = question9,
            Question10 = question10,
            Interview_Id = (int)TempData["id"],
        };
        db.QuestionBlocks.Add(question);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Json(new { Result = "Success", Message = "Saved Successfully" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

But I have error.

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index

What I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Get method

```
 // GET: Questions
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Question1 = new SelectList(db.Questions, "question", "question");
        ViewBag.Question2 = new SelectList(db.Questions, "question", "question");
        ViewBag.Question3 = new SelectList(db.Questions, "question", "question");
        ViewBag.Question4 = new SelectList(db.Questions, "question", "question");
        ViewBag.Question5 = new SelectList(db.Questions, "question", "question");
        ViewBag.Question6 = new SelectList(db.Questions, "question", "question");
        ViewBag.Question7 = new SelectList(db.Questions, "question", "question");
        ViewBag.Question8 = new SelectList(db.Questions, "question", "question");
        ViewBag.Question9 = new SelectList(db.Questions, "question", "question");
        ViewBag.Question10 = new SelectList(db.Questions, "question", "question");
        ViewBag.Vacancy = new SelectList(db.Vacancy, "VacancyId", "VacancyName");
        return View(db.Questions.ToList());
    }
```

Comment: You need to show the `Index` GET method (the POST method is irrelevant). And since it expects an `id`, then it should be `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Questions", new { id = interview.Interview_Id });` and delete all your `TempData` code

Comment: That is not the method the error message is referring to - it would be `public ActionResult Index(int id)`

Comment: So it's Post method. I write to table in Post method.@StephenMuecke

Comment: I solve problem via `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Questions", new { id = interview.Interview_Id });`  . Thank's@StephenMuecke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass id field like below:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Questions", new { id = interview.Interview_Id });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Pass the id to index and you good to go

```
 return RedirectToAction("Index", "Questions", int id here);`
```